# Why is my javascript array length increasing by two when I add a 2 digit number?

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-context

so I am trying to build an amazon clone to learn nextjs. I am trying to use react-context to save the chosen product's id number to an array. the data is being saved and I can access it from any of the components in the project but whenever a product with an id that has 2 digits the array.length increases by 2. here is my code
`

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const AppContext = createContext();

export function AppWrapper({ children }) {
  var [basket, addToBasket]= useState([]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[basket, addToBasket]}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>

  );
}

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}

function Product({id, title, price, description, category, image }) {
 var [basket, addToBasket] = useAppContext();

 const addItemToBasket = () => {
 addToBasket(basket + id);

}

return(
     <button onClick={addItemToBasket} className='button'>Add to Basket</button>
        <h1>items ID in basket: {basket}</h1>
        <h1>length of array: {basket.length}</h1>
     )
```

I did try this and I couldn't get it to work:

```
 let counter = 0;
 
 const addItemToBasket = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) {
   if (basket[i].status === '0') counter++;
 };
 addToBasket(basket + id);

 }

...
```

```
    <h1>length of array: {counter}</h1>
```

I am pretty new to javascript so I did a lot of different variations of this. I gave the for loop its own function, I kept it out on its own but nothing I tried could get it to work. thanks for the help y'all.

Comment: Please read over your post after submitting and then [edit] it to fix any markup mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` returns a getter and a setter, not a getter and a pusher. Your `addToBasket` sets the value of the basket property to `(basket + id)`, which will be a string. More specifically, `basket` is originally an array, but `+` on any arguments that are non-numeric results in a string; once `basket` is a string, `basket + id` will grow the string by the number of characters in the string representation of `id`.

To use the setter correctly:

```
const [basket, setBasket] = useState([]);

const addItemToBasket = () => {
  setBasket([...basket, basket + id]);
}
```